# Flash CS3 - Can this be used to publish stand alone apps and desktop games

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs3

at work and at home I'm trying figure some things out with the deployment of flash. I'm wanting to be able to deploy a flash app as a stand alone application/program. Can this be achieved using flash CS3 (Or CC)  without it looking just like a flash application if that makes any sense? I know there is Air, but I'm wanting to know if there is an independent method instead of using Air.

Giving bit more insight, I'm making an app. From the comfort of your desktop, people can design their own piece of art ( a bit like the generic drag and drops you see online but ours has a save option)and they save design and restore their design.

Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, you're only going to be able to create .swf and .swc (a.k.a. Shockwave) files.  You can try [Project Exporter](http://nipunasthana.wordpress.com/projectorforflashcc/) by Nipun Asthana which will convert it to an .app or .exe.  Alternatively you should try a third-party compiler, or [Zinc by MDM](http://www.multidmedia.com/)

Comment: Hello again, I have come to the same conclusion with Zinc... it does look quality, I've tinkered with it myself but wanted to know if there was anything else out there, not sure if i'm being blind but can you publish to android with zinc?

Have you heard of these?
http://www.flashjester.com/

  - I think you may have commented on one of my other posts actually.

Comment: Zinc is a great solution, and the one we use on our desktop development, however, if you want to target iOS/Android, then Air really is the way to go: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html

Comment: Cheers, yeah I'm starting to come to that realization. Wish there was something out there so that you 'do once and would deploy to all platforms' in one hit, well at least in the dream world. :-) Imagine the time save.